# Should the Sandbox be a featured meta post?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

It always was, and I'm assuming it has just dropped off, so this is just to draw attention to that...

Comment: Community removes the featured tag once a month and, shortly after, a mod adds it again. Just flag the sandbox question.

Answer (score 12):

As Dennis said, there's a cron job that runs every Saturday and removes the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) if it's been used for a month. If you notice this, just flag the sandbox question with a custom flag or let us mods know in the Nineteenth Byte so we can add it again.