# Community Moderator Removing Sandbox featured tag

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, sandbox

If you look in the sandbox edit history there seems to be a long chain of edits where the community moderator removes the featured tag, and a trusted moderator replaces it. This is similar to the issue with it being protected. Is it possible to prevent the community moderator from editing the sandbox question? I don't know how feasible this is.

Comment: related http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8570/community-is-being-overprotective-of-the-sandbox

Comment: Nope, it isn't. IIRC the featured tag automagically wears off, and the mods re-add it.

Comment: Oh, Is it possible to make it permanent?

Comment: Nope. That would need asking the SE Devs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5457/31716). Really, it makes sense why it would be automatically un-featured every month, because other sites have no need to keep things permanently featured.

At first, I had thought this was on our list of requests, but after checking, it was not. So I went ahead and added an answer to our [list of site-specific feature requests](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9831/31716), which is a list of things we want for the site, but can't implement without a lot of SE dev work.

Comment: To add to this, if you see that Community has unfeatured the sandbox, please raise a moderator flag so we can take care of it.

Comment: So basically, what we want is the ability to "Pin" or "Sticky" certain questions.